# Call / Execute chrome extension from a link?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to run/call a Google Chrome extension from a link?

Suppose I have a HTML page with the following link:.

```
<a id="Call-Extension" href="chrome://extensions/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom">Call Extension</a>
```

I want to be able to click on this link, and by doing that execute the extension.

Is that possible?

Comment: By "execute/call" do you mean install the extension or call the already installed extension to do something ? Also, is the HTML local or served from a server ? Do you have access to the HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call it from a URL, no. But, you can use the `contextMenus` Chrome function rather than the typical browser action icon that installs with an extension.

Here's a sample:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Example",

    "name":"Example",
    "icons": {
        "16": "img16.png" }, // Needed for the context menu, but not required

    "background": {
        "scripts":["background.js"] },

    "permissions":[ "tabs", "contextMenus" ], // contextMenus permission allows you to create the action
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

**background.js**

```
//opens a popup window from a selection with a Google search
function sampleSearch(info, tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: "http://www.google.com/?q=" +info.selectionText,
        width: 850,
        height: 670,
        focused:true,
        type:"popup"
    })
}

// Creates the contextMenu action to run the extension
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Search for %s",
    contexts:["selection"],
    onclick: sampleSearch,
})
```

The [Chrome contextMenus documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html) shows how they can be used further.